# How can I introduce a line break in the title for a chapter, but not have the line break in the contents page?

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking, chapters

[image: line break in contents page]

Hello,
I wanted to introduce a line break in some of my titles for aesthetic reasons (to avoid a line with one word)... But now this has seeped into the contents page. Is it possible to have a line break in the title, but not in the contents page?

(this is what I typed in for the chapter heading:
\chapter{The Birth of Stellar \Black Holes})

Comment: `\chapter[one two]{one\\two}`

Comment: @Mico The very first bracket is wrong, probably a typo :) => It should be  \chapter[The Birth of Stellar Black Holes]{...

Comment: Or, `\chapter[The Birth of Stellar Black Holes]{The Birth of Stellar\\Black Hotes}`.

Comment: @henry - Thanks.

Comment: If you define the chapter titles formatting with `titlesec`, just load the latter with option `[newlinetospace]`.